# Java if-else conditions syntax error?

Tags: java

I am trying to run the below program but getting some errors. Can someone help me, understand what is wrong with the conditional statement?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class separatingFirstCharacters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type your name: ");
        String name = reader.nextLine();


        If (name.length()>3) {
            char firstcharacter =name.charAt(0);
            System.out.println ("First character : " + firstcharacter );
            char secondcharacter = name.charAt(1);
            System.out.println ("Second character : " + secondcharacter );
            char thirdcharacter=name.charAt(3);
            System.out.println("Third character: "+thirdcharacter);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("name : " + name);
            }
        }       
    }
```

Console Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method If(boolean) is undefined for the type separatingFirstCharacters
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

    at separatingFirstCharacters.main(separatingFirstCharacters.java:13)
```

Comment: typo: keyword `If` should be lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had 1 compilation issue ('If' should be 'if') and another issue with the third char being the fourth (name.charAt(3) should be name.charAt(2)):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class separatingFirstCharacters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type your name: ");
        String name = reader.nextLine();

        if (name.length() > 3) {
            char firstcharacter = name.charAt(0);
            System.out.println("First character : " + firstcharacter);
            char secondcharacter = name.charAt(1);
            System.out.println("Second character : " + secondcharacter);
            char thirdcharacter = name.charAt(2);
            System.out.println("Third character: " + thirdcharacter);
        } else {
            System.out.println("name : " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is a case sensitive language, and `if` is meant to be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

All java base syntax are case-sensitive and lower-case

if(name.length()>3)

Answer (score 0):

in line
If (name.length()>3) {

change to
if (name.length()>3) {

please note that if should be written in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Please correct he syntax...
It should be:

```
if (name.length()>3) {
     char firstcharacter =name.charAt(0);
     System.out.println ("First character : " + firstcharacter );
     char secondcharacter = name.charAt(1);
     System.out.println ("Second character : " + secondcharacter );
     char thirdcharacter=name.charAt(3);
     System.out.println("Third character: "+thirdcharacter);
    }
     else
       {
         System.out.println("name : " + name);
        }
     }
```